# Can't bind to 'useStickyClasses' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using ngx-stickybits (after npm install ngx-stickybits --save) I import StickybitsModule in my "SharedModule".

In some component (that belongs to a module that imports the shared module) I wrote-

```
<div stickybits [useStickyClasses]="true" [stickToBottom]="false" [stickyOffset]="0" [stuckClass]="is-stuck">
```

But I am getting this error-

Can't bind to 'useStickyClasses' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

What did I forgot to do?

Comment: a reproducible plunker or stackblitz will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to export the `StickybitsModule` from our `SharedModule`